# How to draw SVG on top of canvas?

Tags: android, svg, canvas

I'm doing my application in android studio, 
I have a class that extendes a view  and I'm using it to draw some paths, and I want to add an SVG on top of the canvas,

I know there is a `canvas.drawBitmap();` and a `canvas.drawPicture();`, maybe they can help me draw the SVG in a specific location?

I eventually want a way to show an SVG in the view itself.

Here is my canvas:

```
public class ChessBordWidget extends View {

    public class ChessSlice extends Path {
        public ChessSlice() {
            isInThreat = false;
            threatenedBy = "";
            isOcupied = false;
            color = "white";

        }

        public boolean isInThreat;
        public boolean isOcupied;
        public String threatenedBy;
        public String color;

    }

    Paint paintChessSquareWhite, paintChessSquareBlack, paintChessOuterRim;
    Boolean isTouching = false;
    float touchY, touchX;
    ChessSlice chessSquare;
    ChessSlice framePath;
    ArrayList<ChessSlice> chessPathsArray = new ArrayList<ChessSlice>();

    int width = 340; // default numbers until the screen will change it when it gets the actuall view
    int height = 1200; // default numbers until the screen will change it when it gets the actuall view

    int ROWS_COUNT = 8;
    int COLUMS_COUNT = 8;

    String TAG = "alignmentWidget";

    /**
     * construuctor
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public ChessBordWidget(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.postInvalidate();
        init();
    }

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    public ChessBordWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.postInvalidate();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();

        init();
    }

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyleAttr
     */
    public ChessBordWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.postInvalidate();
    }

    //////////////////////////////////
    //////////////On Draw//////////////
    //////////////////////////////////
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        if (chessPathsArray.size() == 0) { // initlizes the init
            init();
        }

        // draws the first circle
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
//        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2f, height / 2f, OUTER_RING_DIAMETER, firstCirclePaint);

        //go through the array and paints the corisponding cells
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        for (int i = 0; i < chessPathsArray.size(); i++) {
            if (chessPathsArray.get(i).color.equals("white")) {
                canvas.drawPath(chessPathsArray.get(i), paintChessSquareWhite);
            } else {
                canvas.drawPath(chessPathsArray.get(i), paintChessSquareBlack);
            }
        }

        //draw the frame
        canvas.drawPath(framePath, paintChessOuterRim);


    }


    private void init() {
        if (chessPathsArray.size() > 0) { // initlizes the init
            return;
        }

        //gets teh width and height, initlized only after ondraw happend so it wouldn't be 0 0
        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();

        //defining paints
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        paintChessSquareWhite = new Paint();
        paintChessSquareWhite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightChessPiece));
        paintChessSquareWhite.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        paintChessSquareBlack = new Paint();
        paintChessSquareBlack.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkChessPiece));
        paintChessSquareBlack.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        paintChessOuterRim = new Paint();
        paintChessOuterRim.setStrokeWidth(10f);
        paintChessOuterRim.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        paintChessOuterRim.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        // applyes hardware Acceleration
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintChessSquareBlack);
        }

        // gets the main slices paths
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS_COUNT; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLUMS_COUNT; j++) {
                chessPathsArray.add(getSlicesPaths(i, j));
            }
        }

        //draw frame
        framePath = new ChessSlice();
        framePath.moveTo(0, 0);
        framePath.lineTo(width, 0);
        framePath.lineTo(width, height);
        framePath.lineTo(0, height);
        framePath.lineTo(0, 0);

    }


    public ChessSlice getSlicesPaths(int i, int j) {

        int columWidth = width/COLUMS_COUNT;
        int rowHeight = height/ROWS_COUNT;

        int startX = 0+(i*columWidth);
        int startY = 0+(j*rowHeight);

        ChessSlice segmentPath = new ChessSlice();
        segmentPath.moveTo(startX, startY);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX+columWidth, startY);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX+columWidth, startY+rowHeight);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX, startY+rowHeight);
        segmentPath.lineTo(startX, startY);

        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            if ((j % 2) == 0) {
                segmentPath.color = "white";
            } else {
                segmentPath.color = "black";
            }
        } else {
            if ((j % 2) == 0) {
                segmentPath.color = "black";
            } else {
                segmentPath.color = "white";
            }
        }


        return segmentPath;
    }

    private TouchModel calculateTouchSquare (Float touchX, Float touchY) {

        int columWidth = width/COLUMS_COUNT;
        int rowHeight = height/ROWS_COUNT;

        int selectectColum = (int) Math.floor(touchX/columWidth)+1;
        int selectectRow = (int) Math.floor(touchY/rowHeight)+1;

        TouchModel touchModel = new TouchModel(selectectColum, selectectRow);

        return touchModel;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        switch(action){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchX = event.getX();
                touchY = event.getY();
                isTouching = true;
                TouchModel selectedCells = calculateTouchSquare(touchX, touchY);
                Log.d (TAG, "touched: "+touchX+" and: "+touchY);
                Log.d (TAG, "x: "+selectedCells.touchX+" y: "+selectedCells.touchY);

                break;
            default:
                isTouching = false;
        }
        invalidate();

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed it using:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, int drawableId) {
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId);
        } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
            return getBitmap((VectorDrawable) drawable);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can this help in adding SVG on canvas??

Comment: @JimitPatel - right-click your drawable folder, select New, and then Vector Asset. In the dialog, select Local file, change the path, etc., and then you can import your SVG as a VectorDrawable and use this code.

Comment: @rundavidrun thanks for that. But this was too old comment, maybe others can get help out of it. Maybe for more details others can check https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio